# [InvalidScope: Api::BaseController::InvalidScopeError]

Tags: api, coinbase-api

I'm getting the above error when I try to make a money request from my primary account like this:

```
client.getAccount('primary', function(err, account) {
...   console.log(err);
...   account.requestMoney({'to': 'bitdiddle@example.com',
.....                         'amount': '0.1',
.....                         'currency': 'BTC'}, function(err, tx) {
.....     console.log(err);
.....     console.log(tx);
.....   });
... });
```

To be clear, wallet:transactions:send is enabled for the API key I'm using. What's going on??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The `account.requestMoney()` method of the [coinbase-node](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node) library makes a call to the  [Request Money](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#request-money) endpoint, which requires the `wallet:transactions:request` scope, not `wallet:transactions:send`.